# Django - Tutorial - Setting IndexView but Getting TemplateDoesNotExist

Tags: django, angular

I have searched through all the questions here already on TemplateDoesNotExist.
I have also been troubleshooting this for about 12 hours.
There is something I am not understanding. I am new to django.

I am following the following Thinkster tutorial:
[Building Web Applications with Django and AngularJS](https://thinkster.io/django-angularjs-tutorial#registering-new-users)

Here is the error:

**Exception Location:** C:\Users\Workstation333\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py in select_template, line 47

**Exception Type:** TemplateDoesNotExist

**Exception Value:**
index.html

### Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

            Using engine `django`:

- `django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader`: C:\Users\Workstation333\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\index.html (Source does not exist)
- `django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader`: C:\Users\Workstation333\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\index.html (Source does not exist)
- `django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader`: C:\Users\Workstation333\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\templates\index.html (Source does not exist)

This IndexView code I do not understand, and I believe is where the problem lies. The tutorial doesn't go over this code. I think this is what changes the index.html or how to find it. This is inside my views.py and is same project folder where my urls.py is located.

views.py

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import ensure_csrf_cookie
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

    @method_decorator(ensure_csrf_cookie)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(IndexView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

url.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path, include
from rest_framework_nested import routers
from authentication.views import AccountViewSet
from HawkProject.views import IndexView

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'accounts', AccountViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^api/v1/', include(router.urls)),

    re_path(r'^.*$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index')
]
```

partial settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Please help, and Thank you.

Edit:

I added the following to the code, and I got it to not break right away,
but I don't think it is a solution, but a hack that will break, or is not maintainable. I added the index for the admin index inside Dirs like so:

```
 'DIRS': 
['C:/Users/Workstation333/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/Lib/site- 
packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin'],
```

I couldn't find the other index files in the directories where it thinks they should have been. *notice the double admin in the directory above, not sure why that is. It also makes the "home" page take me directly to the admin page.

Comment: Well, do you have an index.html? Where is it?

Comment: I believe it's this one:
C:\Users\Workstation333\Documents\Git\Hawk\HawkProject\templates\index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't read through the tutorial you are doing but try doing this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

As you can see, I think you are getting this error because your template directory `'DIRS'` is blank and as such Django does not know where to search for `'index.html'`. The `'templates'` name can be changed to any name you want but just name it according to the folder which you keep your templates in within each of your apps.

[Django Templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/templates/)

Comment: I did as you say, and I got another perhaps unrelated error about compress is not a registered tag library. So this may the solution, but I need to be sure.

Comment: Usually that happens when you try to load something from an app that isn't yet listed in the INSTALLED_APPS section of the settings.py file. I'm guessing the tutorial wanted you to add something to the installed apps. Try checking the tutorial again. But yeah, I think this error is unrelated.

Comment: Yeah, it was unrelated. Thanks.